# Flutter - Text not visible inside FlatButton with FittedBox

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am learning flutter and trying to design a table consisting of cells with FlatButtons intended to perform some operation. When I am trying to create a TableCell with FlatButton, the FlatButton text is getting rendered vertically and when I am using FittedBox to align it horizontally the FlatButton text disappears, what might be going wrong here and is there any workaround for the same? Please find the code snippet below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: deviceSize.height,
          width: deviceSize.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
              Color(0xffee0979),
              Color(0xffff6a00),
              //Color(0xff29ffc6),
            ], begin: Alignment.bottomRight),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200),
          child: Center(
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              elevation: 15,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                height: deviceSize.height * 0.70,
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Table(
                  border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.2),
                  children: [
                    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                      TableRow(
                        children: [
                          for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                            TableCell(
                                verticalAlignment:
                                    TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: FittedBox(child: Text('Test')),
                                )),
                        ],
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            elevation: 10,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.assignment),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('Instructions')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable time!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not alignment or fitting text inside the cell. It's because the amount of column you put in a row is a lot to be display normally on the screen.

What you can do is to reduce the number of Column:

```
TableRow(
                    children: [
                      for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                        TableCell(
                            verticalAlignment:
                                TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text('Test'),
                            )),
                    ],
                  ),
```

If you want to fit 15 columns in a row without scrollview. Use a SizedBox:

```
TableRow(
                      children: [
                        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 50,
                            child: TableCell(
                              verticalAlignment:
                                  TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                              child: FittedBox(
                                  child: FlatButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                child: Text('Test'),
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Or put the Table inside a SingleChildScrollView with scrollDirection to be horizontal like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Table(
                columnWidths: {
                  0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                  1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                  2: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                  3: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                  4: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                },
                border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.2),
                children: [
                  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                    TableRow(
                      children: [
                        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                          TableCell(
                              verticalAlignment:
                                  TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                              child: FlatButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                child: Text('Test'),
                              )),
                      ],
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks! reducing the number of rows and columns sure does the trick but I need to have 15x15 table here

Comment: I've just updated my answer with additional example for the SizedBox and  SingleChildScrollView case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a container inside the FittedBox to hold the child text might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks... but the behavior is still the same